# Messenger - fb-customerchat - set default messeage or placeholder in JS

Tags: facebook, plugins, chat, messenger

I need to set text in fb-customerchat plugin - question with a date (user could change it before sending). Is it possible?
Or maybe I can create a url like: https://m.me/mypagexxxx?text=15.08.2018%20-%20is%20this%20date%20possible%3F ?

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  logged_in_greeting="Witaj, chętnie odpowiemy na Twoje pytania"
  logged_out_greeting="Witaj, chętnie odpowiemy na Twoje pytania w ciągu 24 h">
</div>
```

How to set default message which user can send to me without writing?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post a) your code so far, b) what you expect to see, c) what you are seeing, d) any error messages. That level of information is required if busy community members are to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible and (even more important) not allowed. The message must be 100% user generated and cannot be prefilled:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Own placeholder in fb-customerchat is not allowed too?

Comment: that would be prefilling, which is not allowed. it is explained in the link of my answer.